# Replace item prices in HTML tags from JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom, getelementbyid

I have a very simple problem, but I just can't figure it out.
My Javascript knowledge is a bit rusty :-)

Here is my JSON data (stored in a file prices.xml)

```
{
"prices": {
"bananas": "2,39",
"apples": "3,39"
}
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<ul>
<LI>Our price for bananas:<SPAN id="bananaprice">BANANA PRICE SHOULD GO HERE</SPAN></LI>
<LI>Our price for apples:<SPAN id="appleprice">APPLE PRICE SHOULD GO HERE</SPAN></LI>
</ul>
```

All i really need is a javascript (no jquery if possible) that pulls the values from the prices.xml and replaces the SPAN values.
I do not need a "hyper flexible" script that does loops and all that.
It has to be super simple.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You have JSON stored in a XML file?

Comment: You mean that you want to make a call to web service or simply the xml file you have in your project directory.

Comment: @ Felix - Yeah the XML extension is a looong story :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery for the AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: yourURL
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data )
    {
        var prices = data.prices;

        $('#bananaprice').text( prices.bananas );
        $('#appleprice').text( prices.apples );
    }
});
```

If you aren't using jQuery or AJAX then you'd need to assign a variable to the object to reference them.

```
var items = {
    "prices" : {
        "bananas" : "$X.XX",
        "apples" : "$X.XX"
    }
};

var banana = document.getElementById('bananaprice'),
    apple = document.getElementById('appleprice')
    price = items.prices;

banana.innerHTML = price.bananas;
apple.innerHTML = price.apples;
```

Comment: Both solutions worked for me!
Thanks a lot guys.

JQuery is my new favourite hehe.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for making my day easier! I wish I had seen this example a few days ago.
I've already upvoted, but +1 for handling the success event.

Answer (score 1):

you should also rename the prices.xml to prices.json and check that your webserver will put the correct mime type on the file.   This not strictly necessary, but in a year when the next guy comes to look over this code they'll wonder why an xml file had json in it.

Comment: Sure, i'll make that change as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON library, or use eval as your data seems safe,See it work here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m6qW7/2/

```
var myPrices = '{ "prices": { "bananas": "2,39","apples": "3,39" }}';
 // string data you got as json

 // added "s" to your span ids for consistency
 var myPricesObj = eval( "(" + myPrices + ")" );
 var prices = myPricesObj["prices"];
 for(fruit in prices)
     document.getElementById(fruit + "price").innerHTML = prices[fruit];
```

Comment: JSON.parse would be better if the browser supports it.