# C# - Sending value to HREF in html

Tags: c#, javascript, html, href

I have written a project in C# in which I load a HTML webpage if an event occurs during teh course of the project usage.

My issue is that inside my html page, I have a href node inside a  tag as such:

```
<a href="http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/flowplayer-700.flv"
            style="display:block;width:inherit;height:inherit;background-color: black;overflow:hidden"
           id="player">
        </a>
```

I would like to change the href value programatically by sending a C# variable (called myHrefFile) depending on what the user did.

How can this be done?

Comment: ajax call perhaps using jason and perhaps using web api http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Asp.Net? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: or look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194268/replace-item-prices-in-html-tags-from-json-data

Comment: Are you using asp.net with c#? if you are why not just use a linkbutton instead? then you can set a listener method for when the user clicks the button

Comment: No, it is a WPF project with a HTML page inside which does not support asp.net I believe.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<a href="<%= someMethodThatGetHrefValue() %>" 
 style="display:block; width:inherit;height:inherit; background-color:black;
 overflow:hidden" 
 id="player">click</a>
```

call the method that decide what should be href for  link .

and put all the logic of deciding href in that method like this

```
public string someMethodThatGetHrefValue()
{
    if(someval == true)
         return "http://www.google.com";
    else
         return "http://www.yahoo.com";
 }
```

Comment: It looks promising but for some reason, when I have a message box read the href once it is loaded, it thinks that the url is : "http://where_my_page_is.com/<%= someMethodThatGetHrefValue() %>" ------ To be clear: I put the C# code in the window that contains the webbrowser. Is that wrong?

Comment: if it is possible to use absolute url then use it. like http://www.domain.com/somepage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps? This is an Asp.net solution.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkBut" runat="server" onclick="LinkBut_Click">Click here</asp:LinkButton></p>

protected void LinkBut_Click(object sender, eventArgs e)
{

    string myHrefFile = "";

    if(Value.equals(true))
    {
     myHrefFile = "page1.aspx";
    }
    else
    {
       myHrefFile = "page2.aspx";
    }

      Response.Redirect(myHrefFile );
}
```